# Find all directories that contain only hidden files and/or hidden directories

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, find, directory

## Issue

- I have been struggling to craft a Bash command that is able to recursively search a directory and then return the paths of every sub-directory (up to a certain max-depth) that contains EXCLUSIVELY hidden files and/or hidden directories.

## Visual Explanation

- Consider the following File System excerpt:

```
+--- Root_Dir
|   +--- Dir_A
|   |   +--- abc.txt
|   |   +--- 123.txt
|   |   +--- .hiddenfile
|   |   +--- .hidden_dir
|   |   |   +--- normal_sub_file_1.txt
|   |   |   +--- .hidden_sub_file_1.txt
|   |     
|   +--- Dir_B
|   |   +--- abc.txt
|   |   +--- .hidden_dir
|   |   |   +--- normal_sub_file_2.txt
|   |   |   +--- .hidden_sub_file_2.txt
|   |    
|   +--- Dir_C
|   |   +--- 123.txt
|   |   +--- program.c
|   |   +--- a.out
|   |   +--- .hiddenfile
|   |   
|   +--- Dir_D
|   |   +--- .hiddenfile
|   |   +--- .another_hiddenfile
|   |     
|   +--- Dir_E
|   |   +--- .hiddenfile
|   |   +--- .hidden_dir
|   |   |   +--- normal_sub_file_3.txt   # This is OK because its within a hidden directory, aka won't be checked
|   |   |   +--- .hidden_sub_file_3.txt
|   | 
|   +--- Dir_F
|   |   +--- .hidden_dir
|   |   |   +--- normal_sub_file_4.txt
|   |   |   +--- .hidden_sub_file_4.txt
```

### Desired Output

- The command I am looking for would output

  ```
  ./Root_Dir/Dir_D
  ./Root_Dir/Dir_E
  ./Root_Dir/Dir_F
  ```

  - `Dir_D` because it only contains hidden files.
  - `Dir_E` because it only contains a hidden file and a hidden directory at the level I am searching.
  - `Dir_F` because it only contains a hidden directory at the level I am searching.

## Attempts

- I have attempted to use the `find` command to get the results I am looking for but I can't seem to figure out what other command I need to pipe the output to or what other options I should be using.
- I think the command that will work would look something like this:

  ```
  bob@linux:/$ find ./Root_Dir -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -name "*." -type -f -name "*." | command to see if these are the only files in that directory
  ```

Comment: You will have to break this into two parts: Directories with some `.files`; Of these, which don't have non `.files`?

Comment: @waltinator Correct, my question is how to do that exactly...

Comment: Is a hidden directory that contains hidden directories considered to be a match?

Comment: @JeremyBoden Yes. The search should only be concerned with a files/directories immediately within the `Dir_N` directory... if there was a hidden directory within `Dir_N` and nothing else, that would be a match. It would not matter what is contained within that hidden directory.

Comment: You could get a flat file with `tree -aif -L 2  root_dir` then perhaps some cunning piece of AWK could do the job???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a less than beautiful solution for this.

In script form:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Echo whatever is passed to fail, and then exit with a status of 1
fail() {
  echo >&2 "$@"
  exit 1
}

# If the number of arguments are less or more than what
# we expect, throw help syntax and exit.
if [ $# -gt 2 ] || [ $# -lt 2 ]
then
  fail "
$0 check for directories that only contain hidden listings
Usage: $0 <Directory to search from> <Depth to check>
  "
fi

# Assign parameters
root_dir=$1
depth=$2

# Find a list of directories that contain files OR subdirectories
# that are hidden
readarray -t dirs < <(export LC_ALL=C
  find "$root_dir" -mindepth "$depth" -maxdepth "$depth" \
    -name ".*" \( -type d -o -type f \) -execdir pwd \; | sort -u
)

# Of the dirs we found, do any of them return any listings with a
# default ls execution? If so, that directory cannot only contain
# hidden listings.
final=()
for dir in "${dirs[@]}"
do
  notExclusive="$(ls -- "$dir")"
  if [ "$notExclusive" = "" ]
  then
     final+=("$dir")
  fi
done

# The array final contains the directories who only contain hidden
# files/subdirectories.
printf '%s\n' "${final[@]}"
```

Basically we just find directories that contain hidden listings (at a depth of 2 as specified in question), load them into an array, and if `ls` with no flags returns nothing, we can conclude that only hidden listings are contained in the directory, which meets our criteria.

To explain why you only need one invocation of `find` per the comments on the OP. The command `find` has operators for your basic logic, -a the default behavior when you join two expressions logical AND, ! as in a logical NOT, and -o as in logical OR.

This approach assumes directory paths don't contain newline characters, if they do `readarray` will incorrectly separate each directory path.

Ugly 'one-liner':

```
readarray -t dirs < <(export LC_ALL=C; find ./Root_Dir -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -name '.*' \( -type d -o -type f \)  -execdir pwd \; | sort -u); final=(); for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do notExclusive="$(ls -- "$dir")"; if [ "$notExclusive" = "" ]; then final+=("$dir"); fi; done; printf '%s\n' "${final[@]}"
```

Comment: I think that this works, however, in practice I'm trying to run it on a path that contains a space, and it throws and error... for example "/Root Dir/Dir A/" instead of /"Root_Dir/Dir_A/" .... If you knew of a way to make it handle paths with spaces it would be perfect. Aside from that it is what I am looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @hf it works fine with spaces. Either use the edited answer (note that your edit would have failed on spaces because you were not quoting the variables, Michael corrected it) or use `"Root Dir/Dir A/"` or  `Root\ Dir/Dir\ A/`.

Comment: @hf I editted the answer to behave more like a generic command since it seems like you want it to function that way.
Thanks to everyone who helped edit my sloppy syntax from yesterday!

Comment: Thank you! Setting mindepth to 0 allows to find all such folders on a drive. The output can then be piped to `| xargs -I{} mv "{}" tmpdir` to visually inspect and remove the folders. You may need to repeat this a few times if there are folder name clashes. You can also use `xargs -I{} trash-put "{}"` if you have trash CLI tools installed.

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`:

```
print -rC1 -- **/*(NDF^e['()(($#)) $REPLY/*(NY1)'])
```

To exclude directories past a certain depth, you can exclude them with the `~` exclusion operator:

```
set -o extendedglob
print -rC1 -- **/*~*/*/*(NDF^e['()(($#)) $REPLY/*(NY1)'])
```

though note that it won't stop `zsh` from descending into them first.

If you only want the ones at depth 2, you can just do:

```
print -rC1 -- */*(NDF^e['()(($#)) $REPLY/*(NY1)'])
```

(though beware it follows symlinks at depth 1)

- `print -rC1` print `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn
- `**/*` recursive globbing
- `(...)` glob qualifiers
- `N`: `N`ullglob: don't complain if there's no match
- `D`: `D`otglob: don't ignore hidden files
- `F`: only `F`ull (with at least one entry other than `.` and `..`) directories.
- `^`: negate following qualifier
- `e['code']`: `e`valuate `code` to determine whether to select the file.
- `()(($#)) args`: returns true if passed at least one arg
- `$REPLY`, within the `code`, holds the file currently being considered.
- `$REPLY/*` the non-hidden files in `$REPLY`
- `Y1`: stop after the first found file.

Answer (score 3):

Using `find` and `bash`, the following command finds all directories.  It then uses `bash` to test whether any of the found directories contain any non-hidden names.  It does this by expanding the `*` glob pattern in each directory and counting the number of names this results in.  If the number is zero, the pathname of the directory is outputted.  The `*` glob pattern does not by default expand to hidden names.

```bsh
find . -type d -exec bash -O nullglob -c '
    for dirpath do
        set -- "$dirpath"/*
        [[ $# -eq 0 ]] && printf "%s\n" "$dirpath"
    done' bash {} +
```

I'm setting the `nullglob` shell option in the in-line `bash -c` script to have the pattern itself removed if there are no matches.

With `/bin/sh`, you don't have access to the `nullglob` shell option, so you will have to test whether the single name that the pattern expands to actually exists.  If it doesn't, the directory contains only hidden names.

```bsh
find . -type d -exec sh -c '
    for dirpath do
        set -- "$dirpath"/*
        [ "$#" -eq 1 ] && [ ! -e "$1" ] && printf "%s\n" "$dirpath"
    done' sh {} +
```

If you want to avoid finding *empty* directories, add `! -empty` before the `-exec` primary of `find` (assuming your implementation of `find` supports this non-standard by common test).

Comment: I like the -exec sh -c pattern that allows for a complex "payload" to -exec inline. Previously, I'd have created a function or another script to do the complicated shell action and then invoked it with a simple -exec expression. A useful pattern to recall.